# Differentiating under the integral sign chain rule

Tags: integration, derivatives

Can someone explain to me why
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{0}^{x\nu}u^{c - 1}{\rm e}^{-u/2}\,{\rm d}u
=
\left(\nu x\right)^{c - 1}{\rm e}^{-\nu x/2}\,\nu\quad {\large ?}
$$
I know it has to do with the application of Chain rule to the integral, but I'm not understanding the intermediate details/steps. Thanks.

Comment: How can I improve it?

Comment: Dunno :-) Let apart the identicon. For your question: you are differntiating w.r.t. a bound of the integral (with an extra multiplication by v). Since $\int_a^{vx} f(x) dx=F(vx)-F(0)$ with F some primitive of f, the result is almost direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=u^{c-1}e^{-\frac{u}{2}}$ and $F(x)=\int f dx$. Then $\int_0^{xv}u^{c-1}e^{-\frac{u}{2}}du=F(xv)-F(0)$. Thus, $\frac{\partial}{dx}\int_0^{xv}u^{c-1}e^{-\frac{u}{2}}du = \frac{\partial}{dx}(F(xv)-f(0))=f(xv)\frac{\partial}{dx}(vx)=(vx)^{c-1}e^{-\frac{vx}{2}}v$.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental theorem of calculus gives that if $f$ is continuous, then the function $\phi(x) = \int_0^t f(t) dt $ is differentiable and $\phi'(x) = f(x)$.

Then, if we let $\eta(x) = \phi(ax)$, we have $\eta'(x) = a \phi'(ax) = a f(ax)$.

In your example,  you have $f(u) = u^{c-1}e^{-\frac{u}{2}}$, $a=v$, so we have the desired result.